# Determine a modal logic formula which a connective that is not valid but is true

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to understand how a formula can not be valid but also true in the above question.

Comment: See [Kripke semantics : Basic definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Basic_definitions): We read $w\Vdash A$ as “w satisfies A”, “A is satisfied in w”. A formula A is valid in a model $\langle W,R,\Vdash \rangle$ , if $w\Vdash A$ for all $w ∈ W$. You have to map "your" true/valid" on "satisfiable/valid in a model".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's consider your task at hand.

We need to write some “properly satisfiable” formula with modalities which is *not valid* **(i.e., there can be some models wherein it can be false)** but *true in the model* on the picture **(i.e., it is true in every world of this model)**.

We assume that we work in **K**, i.e. in minimal normal modal logic where there are no additional conditions on reachability relation (arrows). I also assume that you know relational (Kripke) semantics for normal modal logics.

Let's list some modal formulas of one variable that are true in $x_1,\ldots,x_4$.

- $x_1\vDash\diamond q$ (i.e., you can move one step along an arrow and arrive to $q$); $x_1\vDash\diamond p$ (i.e., you can move one step along an arrow and arrive to $p$);
- $x_2\vDash\Box\Box q$ (i.e., if you make exactly two steps from $x_2$, you'll arrive to $q$)
- $x_3\vDash\Box\Box p$ (i.e., if you make exactly two steps from $x_2$, you'll arrive to $p$)
- $x_4\vDash\Box A$ with $A$ being any formula you want (because, you cannot go anywhere from $x_4$ and formulas with $\Box$ will be vacuously true)

Now, I claim (and leave it to you as an easy exercise) that $$\mathfrak{K}\vDash\diamond q\vee\Box\Box q\vee\Box\Box p\vee\Box A$$ with $\mathfrak{K}$ being your model and $A$ being arbitrary formula.

I also claim (and leave it to you as an a tiny bit more difficult) that this formula is not valid, i.e. we can find a model where it is false (for some $A$).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. It really helped.

Comment: Tbh, there is an even easier answer: simply write $\Box\neg r$: it will be true in every world of your model.